# What should I do to clear everything I have drawn before drawing new things on custom control?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, gdi+, gdi

I have drawn Image on a custom control.

But whenever I draw another Image in the custom control it overwrites or draws **over** it.Can I clear everything I have drawn, before drawing new things?

**MY SOLUTIONS THAT DIDNT WORKED:**

**S1>** I used **this.Invalidate()** which calls the paint event but it is not solving the problem because I already have some code in it which leads to same overdrawing problem.

**S2>** Using **Clear method of Graphics class** solved the problem.
I am using this code to clear everything in my custom control

```
//in my custom controls paint method
    Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
    g.Clear(this.ForeColor);
```

but it is flickering a lot!Thats why I used DoubleBuffered property and now its not showing anything!

Comment: Can't you use `g.Clear(BackColor)`, since its Parent is null?

Comment: If it didn't help you must be painting the same erronous stuff again. What does your paint method do that makes it "draw over old images"? I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: Please don't add `[Solved]` to your title. If you found your own solution post it as an answer and then a day or so accept it. The system will then show the question as "solved". Also you might end up getting reputation from the answer.

Comment: He got it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451009/three-system-drawing-methods-manifest-slow-drawing-or-flickery-solutions-or-oth/2451504#2451504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **flickering** problem has now been solved.
Actually the problem was with the way I created Graphics object.I used this code to create Graphics object:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
```

This caused not only flickering problem but also `DoubleBuffered` property was also not working.

We must actually `use Paint event's e.Graphics` to create Graphics object and then draw.

Thus, now my `DoubleBuffered` property is doing its job..